# Distance considerations between analog output and ADC input?

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi, spi, timing, distance

I have read about distance limitations of timing critical signals like communication over SPI.  In order to get more distance between my Pi and my sensor I am considering using an analog sensor and an ADC.

**Question:**
What should I know when considering the distance between my analog output and my ADC input?  I am, at the moment, considering the impact on:

- Linearity of sensor output and ADC readings
- Delay between sensor output and ADC reading

**Details:**

- Sensor output voltage: 0.25 to 4.75 V
- ADC input voltage: 0 to 5 V
- I hope to sample the sensor output at 50 kHz (seems a bit fast and too fast for SPI over a 1m distance)
- I'm not really sure how to calculate the amperage the ADC will draw from the sensor output.
- [Sensor](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Accelerometer/ADXL193.pdf).
- [ADC](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7579_7580.pdf).

Insight and references are welcome!

**Edit:**

I think a minimum of 8 significant bits is what I can work with.  With a 500 unit range that's a measurement of 1/(2^8*500) = ±2 units.

Comment: Delay is not significant. Noise is a more serious problem. What is the output impedance of your sensor? How many usable dB/significant bits do you want?

Comment: (essentially these are the same problems as faced by audio engineers with microphones on long cables, for which balanced XLR is preferred)

Comment: Interesting, I will read about the audio analogy.  I think I need 8 significant bits and I'm trying to garner the output impedance from the datasheet.

Comment: Cable propagation delay is around 6ns/m -- so not an issue. 5V / 256 (8-bit) = 0.02V of resolution -- should be doable using common good practice. Now consider SPI -- 50kHz sampling rate probably requires around 1Mbps or higher SPI rate, that is 1us cycle time, definitely not too fast. Even using normal 3.3V/5V logic, noise margin can be seen as being in the 0.3V range, that is 10 times higher than the analog margin (0.02V). Follow good practice and series terminate the lines, I wouldn't rule SPI out. The real disadvantage is the need to supply power to SPI device.

Comment: Thanks both, for the comments.  Could you provide either some links to relevant material when considering voltage fluctuations on my signal wire - preferably including the factors that influence this.  Otherwise a few more terms to narrow my search (It seems impedance is relevant - is there a theory or law I could start with?)

Comment: Just had a look at the datasheet and there's a far more important thing you've overlooked: the sensor output is filtered at 400Hz! So you'd be oversampling by 125x. Or you could drop the speed and use SPI happily.

Answer (score 0):

Modern ADCs charge up a tiny capacitor, and then use 20_questions (binary search) to consume that charge with binary-weighted decisions.

The capacitor is approximately 10pF.

The average current will be F*C*V, or 50,000 samples/second * 10pF * 5volts.